# Braket and breqn formatting issues

Tags: breqn

I ran into a problem formatting things with `breqn` and the `braket` style file. A minimal example that illustrates the problem is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

This does not format correctly

\begin{dmath}
   \ket n = (C) = A + B 
\end{dmath}

However, this does
\begin{dmath}
   \ket n = C = A + B
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

The output of which is: [image: This picture]

While in the above example the parentheses are mathematically unnecessary, in the more complicated example I found this in, I need them.

Comment: I get the same result for both lines, using `breqn.sty    2009/08/07 v0.98a`. Could you check your version by adding `\listfiles` in your preamble and looking near the end of the `.log` file?

Comment: Oh, how silly of me. I thought I was up to date, but it turns out I was keeping an old 2008 version in my texmf folder. When I deleted it, I get `breqn.sty 2009/08/07 v0.98a` and my problem is fixed.

Comment: What's the proper etiquette for this post? Do I keep it as is, edit it to highlight my oversight in versions of breqn, or delete it entirely?

Comment: Others might disagree with me, but I'd recommend you answer your own question explaining the steps to determine the problem -- I am sure you are not the only one to encounter such problems.